# What is the use of "memo" while doing transfers?

Tags: transfer

Example in the following transaction details there is a "memo" key, but I cannot find any documentation about it

`eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"scott","to":"exchange","quantity":"1.0000 SYS","memo":""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to optionally describe the transfer. In Steem for example, you see this kind of thing:

[image]